# Switching from Intel (Battery Saver) to GTX 970M doesn't work

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Alienware 17R3, and managed to get the proprietary drivers from the Additional Drivers option.

However, trying to switch to the 970M from the Intel GPU using the task-bar on top simply does not do anything. It asks me for a password:

[image]

But then after logging out and back in it still shows the Intel GPU as the one being used:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

### Edit:

Here's the output of:

```
lspci -k| grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

gnulinux@gnulinux-Alienware-17-R3:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
DeviceName:  Onboard IGD  


Subsystem: Dell Skylake Integrated Graphics

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Dell GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M]
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_361
```

I also tried the following (output included)

```
lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics [8086:191b] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out thanks to some other posts in the community and a bit of intuitive poking around.

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to log into TTY. It asked for my login name and password, and from there I used the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-364
```

Reboot and your graphics issue should be fixed.

**NOTE:** *The proprietary drivers will NOT BE AVAILABLE unless secure boot is disabled in UEFI. The GRUB boot manager works fine though, and it speeds startup a little bit, which is why I was running the computer with Secure Boot on. But the NVIDIA drivers were not available even after the above steps, even though they were installed. Once I switched off Secure Boot, though, it was all smooth sailing!*